# How to get data from a Serialized class C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I want to get data from another class that is serialized, but what a got is "Null"
What do I need to get the data?

```
//This is the serialized class
[Serializable]
public class User1 
{
    public string BB;
    public void Start()
    {
        BB = "hello world";
    }
}


//And This is the other class
public class A1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    User1 user = new User1();

    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Debug.Log(user.BB);

    }
}
```

Comment: From the above code, it doesn't look like you have actually serialized the class yet. You have created an instance of the class. Since the default value string is null (and Start method is not called), user.BB returns null here.

Comment: Serialize method writes to a stream so you can write to a memory stream.  Then set position to zero and read.

Comment: What are you expecting to have set the data? Nothing in the code you posted has either set `BB` directly, or called `user.Start()`. You aren't dealing with a serialized `User1` in class `A1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the `[Serializable]` concept wrong.

The attribute means:

> Indicates that a class can be serialized.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute?view=netframework-4.8

In your code you create new instance of `User1` that's it.

Here is an example of how it works (quick and dirty way):

```
User1 user1 = new User1();
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
Stream stream = new FileStream(@"E:\user1.txt",FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write);

formatter.Serialize(stream, user1);
stream.Close();
```

You get serialized `User1` inside text file.
So now somewhere else in your program you can **deserialize**:

```
stream = new FileStream(@"E:\useri1.txt",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
User1 myuser1 = (User1)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you misunderstood the [`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html). It is a special Unity message that is only called "automatically" for classes derived from `MonoBehaviour`.

`Start` is never called for `user`. So its value of `BB` will always be `null`.

---

You have to invoke the `user.Start()` somewhere e.g.

```
public class A1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    User1 user = new User1();

    private void Start()
    {
        user.Start();
    }

    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Debug.Log(user.BB);
    }
}
```

---

Since you made the class `[Serializable]` you could simply make the field `user` either `public`. `public` fields are automatically serialized if there type is `[Serializable]`. Or if you want to keep it `privte` (most of the times cleaner and better for encapsulation)

```
[SerializeField] private User1 user;
```

so it will be actually serialized → displayed in the Unity Inspector → initialized with a default value `""` which you can then easily edit within Unity.

(From that moment on default values assigned via code have no effect anymore since the serialized value will overrule them.)

---

Otherwise I would suggest you add proper constructors like

```
[Serializable]
public class User1 
{
    // either initialize fields with a default value here
    public string BB = "";

    // Use the default constructor (= without parameters)
    // if you implement other constructors the default constructor
    // is always mandatory for serialization!
    public User1()
    {
        BB = "hello world";
    }

    // use a specific constructor
    public User1(string bb)
    {
        BB = bb;
    }
}
```

Now you can either use

```
User1 user = new User1();
```

so it will have `user.BB = "hello world"`

or you can use

```
User1 user = new User1("Example");
```

so it will have `user.BB = "Example"`

It is then questionable if you even need it to be serializable anymore ...